# Alt +Tab broken in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, window, alt-tab, always-on-top

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> stopped working correctly at some point. The selected application will not rise to the top. It will stay under whatever window is currently selected.

I don't think this is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>b any more. See below.

Oh, and it seems to not be 100% consistent.

I cannot seem to find the answer to this. I tried to follow some registry adjustment instructions found elsewhere, but I didn't even have a 'AltTabSettings' entry in the appropriate spot in my registry. I created one, and adjusted its settings, but I still experience this problem even when I switch it to "XP mode" by setting its value to "1".

After playing some more around with it trying to hunt it down...

I don't think this has anything to do with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (correct, it didn't.) Some windows, when selected, even when DIRECTLY selected, or selected through the taskbar, etc., still won't rise to the top.

At the moment, Chrome stable and Chrome canary windows are doing this (indeed, all applications were doing this.). I guess I need to know where the behavior to indicate when a window should be on top of other windows is handled in Windows (this is like the opposite of the 'always on top' behavior... Or maybe some windows are wrongly being given 'always on top'?).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was related to a conflict between a recent Windows security update and, in my case, the driver for my Lenovo ThinkPad compact external keyboard (not a Lenovo computer or anything, just the keyboard itself). The Hscrollfun.exe process, if I remember right. Killing it finally fixed the behavior.

Unfortunately, I can no longer scroll pages by holding the middle button and the clit mouse. Hopefully this will eventually be fixed, because that is very valuable functionality. Apparently the only other fix at this time is uninstalling the security update, which is not recommended.

Other people experienced similar conflicts with a program called Synergy.

I finally was able to be sure it was from the keyboard, because Windows would only refuse to 'rise to the top' after I had scrolled on them using the middle-click + mousenub functionality. As long as I didn't scroll on it, it would behave normally, and as soon as I would scroll on it, it would sink to the back and act like every other window had 'always on top' above it.

This only JUST got fixed, seemingly by a Windows or Lenovo update; I am not sure. However, sometimes it just won't work now (won't scroll; window order stays fine, though). I'm also occasionally seeing a weird mouse highlight issue that could be related--when I try to highlight text, it will act as if I just dragged it a few lines down, and my cursor will be off by about 30 pixels vertically.